# Get back to sel_getUid()'s original behaviour

Tags: objective-c, selector, objective-c-runtime

**TL;DR:** How does one check that selector with given name was registered, without actually registering it?

Thanks!

---

Hi, I have an Objective-C application and bunch of NSObjects that are exported into Lua state via simple proxy library written in objc. All Lua-side calls like these:

```
exported_objc_object:myMethodName(...)

-- same as --
exported_objc_object.myMethodName(exported_objc_object, ...)

-- same as --
key = 'myMethodName'
exported_objc_object[key](exported_objc_object, ...)
```

are forwarded as if someone called:

```
[objc_object lua_myMethodName:L];

// declared as
- (int)lua_myMethodName:(lua_State *)L { ... }
```

Actually, any 'get' opcode on Lua-exported object returns a cached Lua-closure that on invocation will call corresponding Objective-C method via selector constructed with `sprintf(s, "lua_%s:", key))` && `sel_getUid(s)` (all checks included). If produced selector is not implemented in terms of `-[respondsToSelector:]`, then `exported_objc_object.myMethodName` simply returns `nil`.

Obviously, proxy library has to make dynamic lookups via `sel_getUid()` or `sel_registerName()` (I believe both `@selector` and `NSSelectorFromString()` also end up there). The manual states that `sel_getUid()` was intended to lookup selector names (as opposed to immediately registering them into SEL registry), but it's modern implementation now does the same as `sel_registerName()` due to bugs in someone's teh codez back then.

I can just stick with `sel_registerName()` behavior, but that leaves memory-eating attack vector, as some malicious script may start looking up long random/invalid selectors via sml `object[makeRandomKey()]` in a loop, thus overflowing SEL registry forever. If `sel_getUid()` worked as planned, proxy lib would be able to test selector presence and only then actually check if object responds to it, without excessive registering. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a hack that might work, that uses the implementation-dependent fact that a selector is a C string.

```
sel_isMapped((SEL)(void *)"lua_myMethodName:")
```